# VB Newtonsoft JSON.Net "Could not load file or assembly"

Tags: vb.net

I am using [JSON.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to get my Console application to translate sentences with Google Translate. My code fully works fine with absolutely no errors when I run it in Visual Studio. But when I take the .exe out of the "[project_name]\bin\debug" folder and copy it to the desktop to run it returns the following exeception.

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified....

I noticed that in my "[project_name]\bin\debug" folder [there is the .dll file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfJmy.jpg) that I am using, but not only this, I am also using a .dll [that I referenced somewhere else](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfq2b.jpg).

When I drag this .dll file with the exe onto the desktop and run it, it works. How do I make it so that I don't need the .dll with the .exe on the desktop? Or is this something that is necessary? I am sure that I have [referenced everything properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjAaX.jpg).

Answer (score 0):

If your application makes use of a library then that library has to be there to make use of. There are basically two ways to make libraries available to .NET applications. The library needs to either be in the same folder as the application or it needs to be installed in the GAC (Global Assembly Cache). The GAC is a common location for libraries so that multiple applications can access them. Unless you intend to ensure that JSON.NET is installed in the GAC on every machine you plan to run your app on, you need to make sure that the library is deployed along with your app. This is how applications work. There is no magic solution.

Comment: Oh I see, how do I actually setup a GAC?

Comment: You don't "setup a GAC". If you want to learn about the GAC, you should do some research and reading on the GAC. As it stands, you don't even know whether installing to the GAC is practical in this case.

Comment: In the end, I just created a setup wizard for the program which has a dependency of the .dll and .NET; It works.